# Passando props entre componentes

Tags: javascript, react

Bom dia, em um cenário com 3 componentes, sendo eles CaseCard, CasePage e Portfolio, onde CaseCard é um card que eu declaro dentro de Portfolio com a imagem, titulo e descrição que eu desejo, e CasePage deve ser a página específica do CaseCard clicado. Não consigo transferir as props do componente clicado para CasePage, como são vários não posso só exportar cada componente.

No meu router tenho a rota:

```
<Route path="/casepage" component={CasePage} />
```

CaseCard:

```
import React from 'react'
import './CaseCard.css'

export default props => (

<div className="col-4 img__wrapcase pointer">
  <img src={props.src} className="img-fluid" alt={props.alt}/>
  <div className="img__description_layercase">
    <div className="img__descriptioncase">
      <h4 className="nomargin">{props.cliente}</h4>
      <hr className="colorwhite"></hr>
      <h6>{props.campanha}</h6>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
)
```

Portfolio:

```
import React from 'react'
import './CaseCard.css'
import CaseCard from './CaseCard'
class Portfolio extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
    <div className="container portfolio">
       <CaseCard
           src="exp.jpg"
           alt="exemplo"
           cliente="fulano"
           campanha="loremipsumblablabal"
       /> 
       <CaseCard
           src="exp.jpg"
           alt="exemplo1"
           cliente="fulano"
           campanha="loremipsumblablabal"
       /> 

       <CaseCard
           src="exp.jpg"
           alt="exemplo2"
           cliente="fulano"
           campanha="loremipsumblablabal"
       /> 

       <CaseCard
           src="exp.jpg"
           alt="exemplo3"
           cliente="fulano"
           campanha="loremipsumblablabal"
       /> 
    </div>

    )
  }
}
export default Portfolio
```

CasePage:

```
import Portfolio from './Portfolio'
import React from 'react'

class CasePage extends React.Component{   

    render(props){
        return(
            <div className="container">
                <Portfolio/>
            </div>

        )
    }
}

export default CasePage
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode definir uma função no seu CasePage e passar via prop ou Context para o CaseCard e, quando for clicado, você chama a função do CasePage.

Exemplo:

```
import Portfolio from './Portfolio'
import React from 'react'

class CasePage extends React.Component{

    onCaseCardClick = () => {
        // Faça alguma coisa aqui
    }
    render(props){
        return(
            <div className="container">
                <Portfolio onCaseCardClick={this.onCaseCardClick}/>
            </div>

        )
    }
}

export default CasePage

class Portfolio extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
    <div className="container portfolio">
       <CaseCard
           src="exp.jpg"
           alt="exemplo"
           cliente="fulano"
           campanha="loremipsumblablabal"
           onClickCallback={this.props.onCaseCardClick}
       />
    </div>
    )
  }
}


export default props => (

<div onClick={() => props.onClickCallback()} className="col-4 img__wrapcase pointer">
  <img src={props.src} className="img-fluid" alt={props.alt}/>
  <div className="img__description_layercase">
    <div className="img__descriptioncase">
      <h4 className="nomargin">{props.cliente}</h4>
      <hr className="colorwhite"></hr>
      <h6>{props.campanha}</h6>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
)
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! Só pra confirmar, a chamada de função vai ser passada por props partindo de CaseCard -> Portfolio -> CasePage, e então por fim, na CasePage, é onde ocorre a declaração da função, e eu consigo tratar os dados, acessando por props ou context?

Comment: Você vai passar a referência da função declarada em CasePage para o CaseCard via props. Quando CaseCard for clicado, a função declarada em CasePage vai ser executada.

Usando context seria da seguinte forma:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vgbx27

Se vc tiver mais dúvidas sobre o uso do Context API, dê uma lida na documentação que é bem bacana https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/context.html